# Hibernte 5.4.13 lazy loading suddenly doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

I'm facing yet another frustrating issue with Hibernate.
We are currently on version 5.4.11 but I need to upgrade it at least to version 5.4.24 due to some serious CVE vulnerabilities (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core).

But everything from 5.4.13 and on behaves differently in terms of lazy loading and our tests suddenly started to fail.

The `company` field on employment entity should be a proxy object, same as `systemLanguage`  and it actually is on 5.4.11, but not on 5.4.13 and newer..
I already read throughtout the entire internet and found nothing in that regards. Tried many things but the company is still being fetched eagerly even though it is defined as `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ...`

Any ideas what might've gone wrong?
[debugging screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHBgg.png)
[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9RnA.png)

When I enable query logging, I see that Hibernate just suddenly executes two selects one for employment and one for company (just when I try to fetch employment by id).

Comment: Just one theory: such problem can happen when one uses Lombok's @Data annotation. Do you use it?

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for reaction. We don't use Lombok at all